# Fetching contents of .eh_frame section from the elf file

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, elf

I am supposed to fetch the field pc_begin and pc_range from the .eh_frame section of the elf file.
The format of this section is described in here: https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_3.0.0/LSB-PDA/LSB-PDA/ehframechpt.html

I have the starting address of the section with me:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ehdr->e_shnum; i++) {
           if(strcmp((sh_strtab_p + shdrs[i].sh_name),".eh_frame") == 0){
                size = shdrs[i].sh_size;
                addr= shdrs[i].sh_addr;
           }
}
```

This addr is in uint64_t type.
Using this address as the starting point, I have been reading 4bytes of data to fetch the length field of CIE/FDE record and 8bytes to get the extended length field.

```
static uint64_t start = addr;
for(uint64_t start= addr;start <  (addr+size);){
     uint32_t initial_length= ReadFourBytes(start);
     start += 4;

     if (initial_length == 0xffffffff) {
         initial_length =ReadEightBytes(start);
         start += 8;
     }
     else if ( initial_length == 0){
         printf("No CFI information\n");
         exit(0);
     }

     else{
     }
     static uint64_t temp_addr= start;
     uint32_t CIE_id = ReadFourBytes(start);

     if (CIE_id == 0){
         printf("CIE record\n");
         start = start + initial_length;
         continue;
     }

     else{
         printf("Fde record\n");
         start+=4;
         uint64_t pc_begin= ReadEightBytes(start);
         printf("PC_Begin %x", pc_begin);
         start+=8;
         uint64_t Size= ReadEightBytes(start) - Address;
         printf(" %x\n",Size);
         start = temp_addr + initial_length;
     }

 }
```

To keep proceeding and to read other fields, I need to increment my start variable. I know this isn't the proper code.

I have been working on this for quite sometime. Any kind of help would be appreciated and gladly accepted.

Comment: And how exactly do you propose to become a shining tower of knowledge in future?

Comment: `uint32_t four_bytes = *(uint32_t*)ptr; ptr += 4; unit64_t eight_bytes = *(uint64_t*)ptr;`

Comment: After incrementing by 4 bytes, your pointer won't be on an 8-byte boundary.

Comment: That's incorrect @john

Comment: @TanveerBadar How so?

Comment: `++ptr;` since it is pointing to a 64-bit entity, or not even that. These types of questions hardly teach anything and are full of tricks.

Comment: The OP says the type of ptr is `uint64_t` not `uint64_t*`.

Comment: @john which doesn't explain a lot. "Increment"? Increment to point to next byte? int? long? somewhere in the middle? What if you end up doing unaligned data access? Imagine a 64-bit word machine which doesn't allow unaligned reads.

Comment: Can we please close such questions! If we are in c++ we don't have any need to fetch manually 4 bytes from whatever. We have objects and should learn to use them and not reinventing assembler on c++ level with 8bit cpu in mind. Thanks!

Comment: I imagine the OP means increment beyond the last fetch. And obviously I'm not claiming this is portable code.

Comment: @Klaus I completely disagree. C++ is a tool, if you can write useful code in it then that's good. Of course portable code is good, but not all problems can be solved with portable code.

Comment: @john: Nobody knows what type of pointer ptr is. If it is a pointer to uint64_t any incr will go to next full uint64_t whatever it is alligned or not. incr by 4 of maybe a char pointer points to 4 chars behind the first address of an uint64_t but that is not necessarily the next uint64_t!

Comment: @Klaus The OP says `I have a memory address in uint64_t`. That's completely clear.

Comment: @john Would you agree that this is also a valid interpretation of the question description? `uint32_t four_bytes = *(uint32_t*)ptr; ++ptr; unit64_t eight_bytes = *(uint64_t*)ptr;`

Comment: @john: Accessing data of any kind of data structure can be written portable. But not with casting to wrong pointer types, assuming any memory layout which can change by any compiler update or change of compiler itself or by using the code on different platform or OS. If you are dealing with memory mapped IO on kernel driver level, you can start thinking of pointer gymnastics, but not in c++ for nothing.

Comment: @TanveerBadar No I would not. Of course the OP might have expressed themselves wrongly, but I'm just answering the question asked.

Comment: @john "I have a memory address in uint64_t" which is the start of the problem. Why someone should have a pointer in a integer var. That is the first failure!

Comment: @john I am also answering the question as I see fit. That's why this question deserves to be closed. It is not teaching anyone anything.

Comment: @Klaus Maybe but I'm just answering the question that was asked. We don't know anything about the OP's situation. It could be that they could rewrite their code in a more portable way, but we don't know that unless the OP adds more detail

Comment: @john: "We don't know anything about the OP's situation. " Furthermore we did not know what he really wants to achieve! Using an int var to address something is wrong. And as nobody knows what the question is really asking, we vote to close! This gives OP the hint to be more precise or even OP sees that the startpoint is far away from a solution at all and another look in a primer book is best. Both is very helpful while wrong pointer arithmetic's on unknown platforms which are never portable are not !